# CKEditor changes blockquote to p

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor changes `blockquote` to `p`

I enter this, in the "source view mode":

```
<blockquote>asdf</blockquote>
```

After toggling "Source" off and on again, the `blockquote` was changed to a `p`:

```
<p>asdf</p>
```

This happens in my installation, and on this demo site, too: http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets

It does not happen in the standard demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo#standard

Why does `blockquote` get changed?

Answer (score 1):

Because of [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) - there is no feature that would allow `<blockquote>` support in these editor configurations, so ACF removes these elements.

You need to either add the [Blockquote plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/blockquote) to support this feature or [extend your ACF configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf-section-automatic-mode-and-allow-additional-tags%2Fproperties) to accept `<blockquote>` elements.

For example:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'blockquote';
```

Note that if you want to also support classes, attributes or inline styles for these additional elements, your configuration needs to include them, too.

Check these SDK demos, too:

- [Advanced Content Filter – Automatic Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html)
- [Advanced Content Filter – Custom Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acfcustom.html)